# Silent push notification has a sound in iOS with FCM, How to fix?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ios13

I've implemented Silent push notification, but it has a sound like the normal ones. Help me to correctly implement this.

Here's the payload that we're sending from Backend to FCM:

```
{
    "notification": {
        "messageId": "24d0f68a24d"
    },
    "content_available": true,
    "data": {
        "requestId": "231DDD",
        "messageId": "f68a24d",
        "event": "REMOVE_NOTIFICATION",
        "message": ""
    },
    "apns": {
        "headers": {
            "apns-push-type": "background",
            "apns-priority": 5
        }
    },
    "to": "FCM_Token",
    "priority": "high"
}
```

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: @DilanAnuruddha the silent push has a sound, it shouldn't have, what am I doing worng?

Answer (score 0):

**To make this silent, you have to remove following part.**

```
"notification": {
    "messageId": "24d0f68a24d"
},
```

Comment: I've tried this, resulting the silent push isn't received